# Parallel connecting USB power for higher currents

Tags: power, usb, resistance, parallel

I am trying to find any way in which I can have a higher power output from a USB power bank, by combining multiple USB ports in parallel. The USB power bank has 3 outputs, one rated at 2.1A and the other two rated at 1A. How do I do this exactly?

One idea would be to use a splitter cable and then combining multiple ports to one, but how would the power be distributed across the wires? I don't think a thin USB power wire is able to handle > 4 amps. Any solution to resolve this issue?

Comment: Give us more information about what you'd actually like to accomplish if you can.  Using multiple USB ports of a computer in the way you're describing could be disastrous.  For USB chargers, you would have to look at the design of the individual driver to evaluate how it will share a load.  Do you simply want 4 amps available at 5 volts for some external device?

Comment: Yes, it is drawn from a powerbank

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question a few days ago? I remember a question with the exact same configuration (USB power bank, one 2.1A port, two 1A ports, requirement for > 4A) and I thought it got answers. Was there a problem with those previous replies? Why repeat the question?

Comment: Found it - same user name, but different account: "[Higher current draw from powerbank?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/388142/higher-current-draw-from-powerbank)". Please, don't repeat questions. If you need additional clarification, then ask for that in the *original* question, so that we can see the history and context, and we don't waste time starting from the beginning again.

Comment: Can a y splitter be used for parallel connecting the usb cable

Comment: Open up your powerbank case, and try to determine if all VBUS pins on all three connectors (I assume Type-A receptacles) are connected together. Or try to measure continuity between VBUS pins. Post update.

Comment: @Ali - Hi, Didn't you already give effectively the same advice in [your answer to the OP's previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/388190) (without any response from the OP)? It just seems like this is a repeat of what's been done before...

Comment: @SamGibson *"already give effectively the same advice"* ... maybe, there are so many dumb questions so it is difficult to track them, and try to remember if you really answered it, or just was thinking to answer them, but forgot to hit the "post" button". And I really dislike this kind of "ask and run" incidents.

Comment: @AliChen - All understood, thanks, I just wasn't sure if you'd seen it was the same OP asking some of the same questions, where you'd already kindly spent time answering. None of us want to waste time on duplicates, I think.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on powerbank construction. This [teardown video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eqAdZibP1Vo) of Anker 20100 powerbank (two outputs) indicates that one can draw 4 A by using two ports in parallel, around 10:00.